# How do I properly update a list property in my database using EF Core CF

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, sqlite, entity-framework-core

This is what I'm thinking, I want a database that creates a row for each item, each row will have a set of columns, these columns might look like this

```
Id(pk), ItemId, itemBuyPrice, itemSellPrice
```

However I also want to store a collection of `datapoints` which resembles a `datepoint` object which stores things such as long `dateInSeconds` (epoch time), price at this point etc.
So each item will have a list of datapoints which will be used for graphs.

The issue I'm facing is that, once every day, that collection needs to update because the API updates obviously and displays the most recent date.
How would I update that list using EF Core?

This is what I have so far, I add data like this..

```
try
                    {
                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 2,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                        {
                          new DataPoints { ItemId = 2, Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 },
                          new DataPoints { ItemId = 2, Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 }
                        }
                        });


                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 3,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                        {
                          new DataPoints { ItemId = 3, Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 }
                        }
                        });

                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 4,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                        {
                          new DataPoints { ItemId = 4, Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 }
                        }
                        });

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
                    catch (Exception e)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(e);
                        throw;
                    }

                }
```

And then I comment that out, to try to update the datapoints for each item with this code

```
var dp = ctx.Items.Include(x => x.Datapoints).FirstOrDefault(x => x.ItemId == item.ItemId).Datapoints;
                    foreach (var datapoint in dp)
                    {
                        ctx.Datapoints.Remove(datapoint);
                        ctx.SaveChanges();

                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 2,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                            {
                              new DataPoints { ItemId = 2, Time = 200000, Buy = 210, Sell = 210 },
                              new DataPoints { ItemId = 2, Time = 200000, Buy = 210, Sell = 210 }
                            }
                        });


                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 3,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                            {
                              new DataPoints { ItemId = 3, Time = 200000, Buy = 210, Sell = 210 }
                            }
                        });

                        ctx.Items.Add(new ItemModel
                        {
                            ItemId = 4,
                            Buy = 100,
                            Sell = 100,
                            Datapoints = new List<DataPoints>()
                            {
                              new DataPoints { ItemId = 4, Time = 200000, Buy = 210, Sell = 210 }
                            }
                        });

                        ctx.SaveChanges();
                    }
```

And as of right now, it throws an exception saying that the collection has been modified and it can't continue after it changes the first item.

Here is all the code
https://hatebin.com/eeldpnbeaf

Answer (score 1):

You will have to get the data from the database and update it, something like this:

```
// 

List<Datapoints> pointsToUpdate = new List<DataPoints>()
                        { 
                          new DataPoints { Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 },
                          new DataPoints { Time = 100000, Buy = 200, Sell = 200 }
                        }
                    }

// You will need the id of the item for wich you want to update the Datapoints collection and the datapoits class should have the itemId 

class DataPoints
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Time { get; set; }
        public int Buy { get; set; }
        public int Sell { get; set; }
        public int ItemId {get;set;}
    }



// update the dataPoints with the new values
// here you need a for loop to update the values

using (MyContext ctx = new MyContext()) { 

                foreach (var item in pointsToUpdate)
                {
                       // get the points
                    var dp = ctx.Datapoints.Where(dps => dps.ItemId == item.ItemId).ToList();
                    foreach (var datapoint in dp)
                    {
// condition to make the update (if....)
                        if(item.ItemId == datapoint.ItemId)
                        {
                            datapoint.Time = item.Time;
                            datapoint.Sell = item.Sell;
                            datapoint.Buy = item.Buy;
                            ctx.Datapoints.Update(datapoint);
                        }//endif
                    }
                }//end the for here
//save the changes
                ctx.SaveChanges();
            }
```

Something like this. This should work.

Comment: You update the entire list but you should update itemPoint.

Comment: Sorry, here.. https://i.imgur.com/HCsMP4l.png That's what I'm doing and it's not doing anything at this point. But it's not throwing any errors

Comment: man, you should use ctx.SaveChanges(); after the loops. And you should have some logic in the foreach because nou you will update all items with the same values.

Comment: That didn't do anything different, it still doesn't update any data.

Comment: I did this ` ctx.Datapoints.Where(dp => dp.ItemId == item.ItemId).ToList();` when I was suppose to do this.. `apiData.Where(dp => dp.ItemId == item.ItemId).ToList();`.. However, that leaves me with double data points https://i.imgur.com/3Ji5Tnf.png

Comment: Then I won't be able to access the database context

Comment: This should work, I have tested the code and is working.